# Compile multiple files into one with title blocks

Tags: pandoc

I'd like to know how to compile multiple pandoc files into one output document, **where each input file has a title block**.

E.g. suppose I have two files:

`ch1.md`:

```
% Chapter 1
% John Doe
% 1 Jan 2014
Here is chapter 1.
```

`ch2.md`:

```
% Chapter 2
% Jane Smith
% 3 Jan 2014
Here is chapter 2.
```

Typically with multiple input files you can compile them by providing them to pandoc:

```
pandoc ch1.md ch2.md --standalone -o output.html
```

However pandoc concatenates the input files before compiling, meaning only the *first* title block (from `ch1.md`) is styled appropriately.
I would like *each* title block to be styled appropriately (e.g. in html, the first line of the title block is styled with `<h1 class="title">`, the second `<h2 class="author">` and so on).

(Note: I have also tried compiling each chapter as standalone separately, then concatenating these together using `pandoc`. This removes the title styling for chapters after 1, though keeps styling for the authors/date).

**Why?** I can:

- compile each chapter in its own separate document and the author/title/date is marked up appropriately
- compile the entire document together and author/title/date is marked up appropriately for each chapter (can use the `--chapters` option)

I could just specify the heading with '#' (h1), author with '##' (h2), and date with '###' (h3) in each chapter file directly but this means pandoc doesn't "know" what the title/heading/date of my document are, so (e.g.) if I compile to latex it won't use the `\date{}` or `\author{}` tags appropriately.

Comment: You probably want to compile them separately, then concat them with a pdf concatter. I'll bring this question to the attention of the mailing list, in hope that someone would have a better solution.

Comment: @Shahbaz - I don't want to be constrained to PDF, but yes that'd work if I was interested in PDF output. I've hacked together a good-enough solution for now.

Comment: Try `pandoc ch1.md ch2.md --standalone -o output.html --file-scope`. According to documentation this will "*Parse each file individually before combining for multifile documents. This will allow footnotes in different files with the same identifiers to work as expected. If this option is set, footnotes and links will not work across files. Reading binary files (docx, odt, epub) implies --file-scope.*"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wrote a [pandoc filter](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html) that when run on each individual chapter's file, inserts the title block as headings (level 1 for title, level 2 for author, level 3 for date. This is what the HTML writer does).

This lets you run pandoc on each chapter individually (to produce the pandoc'd output plus the formatted title block), and then run pandoc on all the chapters *together* to compile the single document.

The filter is here on gist (I take no responsibility for malfunctioning code, etc): https://gist.github.com/mathematicalcoffee/e4f25350449e6004014f

You could modify it if you wanted it to format differently (for example like this the author/date appear in the table of contents since they are headings, which is not quite right... but that's a different problem as it happens with the default HTML writer too).

My workflow is now something like this:

```
FORMAT=latex  # as understood by -t <format> in pandoc
FLAGS=--toc   # other flags for pandoc, --smart, etc
OUT=pdf       # output extension
for f in Chapter*.md; do \
    pandoc $FLAGS -t $FORMAT --filter ./chapter.hs $f; \
    echo ""; \
done | pandoc $FLAGS --standalone -o thesis.$OUT
```

where I've `chmod +x chapter.hs` and it's in the current directory.

(I additionally have a `title.txt` that I stick out the front with the entire thesis' title block (as opposed to each chapter's title block)).

I received some help from the [pandoc google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/cT-M9gGT5A4) which was great.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the `%` title blocks, but you can do it with the new YAML title blocks.

Start each document like this:

```
---
title:  Chapter One
author:  Me
date: June 4
...
```

When the documents are concatenated together, the first value set will take precedence over the others, so the subsequent YAML lines using the same parameter (e.g. "title:") will be ignored. (See the [readme](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) under "Extension: yaml_metadata_block".)

Comment: This works to compile each doc individually, but when I compile the docs together I lose the headings etc for subsequent chapters (since the subsequent YAML blocks are ignored). At the moment I just have a Makefile that replaces the % block with '#', '##' etc for the title/author/date when compiling separate documents together (demote title blocks to chapters). I guess I should write a proper script to demote each heading by one level when compiling a documents as a chapters? (I guess with latex you have to pick say the first chapter as the document heading/author).