# How can I use the command `runhaskell`?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to run the Haskell script in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247978/compile-multiple-files-into-one-with-title-blocks/23400453#23400453). Pandoc appears to execute the `runhaskell` executable because I get the error

```
Could not find executable runhaskell
```

Seems like I need Haskell. So I google "install haskell", go to [haskell.org](https://www.haskell.org/platform/), and follow the install instructions. It appears to install correctly. For example, I now have a `$HOME/.ghcup/` directory and the `stack` command works. However, `runhaskell` still does not work. When I [search Haskell Tool Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/search.html?q=runhaskell), I don't see any meaningful hits. However, there is a `stack` command called `runhaskell`. When I add `stack runhaskell` to the top of `chapter.hs` from the previous post, I get the same error.

I even tried following a ["hello world"](https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_in_5_steps) for Haskell but the first step, using `ghci`, fails. So maybe I didn't even install the Haskell Platform correctly.

Feels like a really stupid issue, but I can't figure out how to install the executable `runhaskell` which, I assume, will run a Haskell program.

Comment: looks like `runhaskell` is not in your `$PATH`

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Sorry, the installer asked if I wanted to add something `ghcup`-related to my `$PATH`, but this was (clearly) not the binary.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like runhaskell is not in your $PATH